# Reallocating to the same size causes invalid next size error

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, exec, realloc

So this is kind of complicated to explain but I'll try my best.

I'm getting

> realloc(): invalid next size  Aborted (core dumped)

But only when I try to realloc the vector to the same old size.

The program reads input from the terminal in this format with a max of 3 arguments:

> p1 p1arg1 p1arg2 -> p2 p2arg1 p2arg2 p2arg3

Then it proceeds to tokenize and get the path, program name and arguments ready for using the SVC execv. (e.g.):

> execv(prog_path,prog_args);

where

> prog_path is "path/to/p1"
>   and
>
> prog_args is "p1","p1arg1","p1arg2",NULL

PS: There are 2 arguments in the exemple, but execv needs to have the program name and NULL as first and last elements.

So I have these two functions and main just call them in sequence:

```
// current terminal input
char* input;

void read_input() {
  // reads input from terminal
  size_t bufsize = 32;
  input = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
  getline(&input,&bufsize,stdin);
  input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
}

void op_execute() {

  // Tokenize input
  // Example: [prog1] [arg1] [->] [prog2] [arg1] [arg2]
  char* token = strtok(input, " ");

  while (1) {
    // First token is program path
    char* prog_path = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    // Next tokens are program arguments
    // First arg is prog name and last arg is NULL
    char** prog_args;
    prog_args = malloc(5);
    char* prog_name = strrchr(prog_path,'/');
    if (prog_name) {
      prog_args[0] = malloc(strlen(prog_name));
      strcpy(prog_args[0],prog_name);
    }
    else {
      prog_args[0] = malloc(strlen(prog_path));
      strcpy(prog_args[0],prog_path);
    }
    int i = 1;
    while (token && strcmp(token,"->") != 0) {
        prog_args[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(token));
        strcpy(prog_args[i],token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    prog_args = realloc(prog_args,(i+1));
    prog_args[i] = NULL;

    // TEST
    printf("program: %s\n",prog_path);
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
        printf("arg(%d): %s\n",j,prog_args[j]);
    }

    if (!token) {
      break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

It will only raise the error if there are 3 args, with 0,1 or 2 args it works. I thought about checking if the size is the same but it feels like I'm running away from the problem.

Comment: `prog_args` is not big enough. If a pointer is 4 bytes, `malloc(5)` only allocates enough space for 1 pointer. As soon as you write to `prog_args[1]` you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: `malloc(5)` only gives you space for five *bytes*. The realloc isn't right either, only askign fro `(i+1)` *bytes*. And none of your arg allocations are providing space for the terminator. set as part of string copy, so those are invoking undefined behavior as well.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you've forgotten that when you call `malloc()` or `realloc()` you need to multiply the number of elements by the size of each element.

Comment: You should use something like `prog_args = malloc(5 * sizeof(*prog_args));` and `realloc(prog_args,(i+1) * sizeof(*prog_args));`. (I didn't check if the numbers `5` and `(i+1)` make sense.) Probably you should do the `realloc` in the loop instead of after the loop.

Comment: `realloc` _can_ (and on Mac _will_, in debug mode) return a different address. Even when the size is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the the tips everyone and thanks for the snipped Bodo, that worked. Loop is in the right place though. Everything works, life is good.